# php and the "white page of death" - would it apply to API too?

Tags: php, api

I've done a bit of php and I've had my fair share of "white pages of death".

Some friends are working on a server API which they want to implement with php. The APIs conceptually are independent modules. But they will be deployed on the same physical server running the same apache instance.

So my question: will those modules really be that independent? Would the "white page of death" not also possibly apply to APIs? They say they will have independent classes for each module, but my guess is they all will be running in the same php memory space - so if one of the modules has a severe flaw (in worst case a white page of death trigger), wouldn't this affect all the other modules as well, bringing them effectively down as well?

I apologize if I pose this question as a low-experienced php guy, and if more information would be needed in order to properly answer this question.

AFAIK they don't even use a framework, it's all handish.

Comment: white page of death? Thats a new one to me. Does that mean a blank page?

Comment: If there's a conflict within any piece of code, or your current PHP version does not meet the requirements of the API, it'll throw errors (using functions not yet implemented in your version. So essentially, the white screen of death can be triggered by a number of things. Could originate from the api it's self, OR could originate by you not correctly using it

Comment: To me, a _white page of death_ means nothing was sent to the browser or error reporting was turned off.  What is this WPOD you speak of?

Comment: I'm surprised so many don't recognize this term. Here is some info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death

Comment: And if you're serious about the downvote, please add at least a reason why. This is a pretty valid question imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "same php memory space". Each http request and the php code running inside to handle it are completely independent of each other.

A bug in one or more of your api scripts,e.g. a syntax error causing a fatal parse error at startup, WOULD kill all of your requests using those scripts, but not by reaching into memory and fiddling there. It'd be killing them by preventing them from starting up in the first place when a new request comes in